# Google Drive API list files I own in SharedWithMe view

Tags: google-drive-api

In a specific Google Drive, there is a folder shared with me.
In this folder I create a folder (I'm the owner of this folder) or I create a file (I'm owner of this file).
However this folder and file appear only in my Sharedwithme view despite the fact that I'm owner of them.

I want to programmatically retrieve these files using Google Drive SDK.
If I run a query (q=sharedwithme), it returns only the root sharedfolder (my folder and file is within this sharedfolder).

It looks simple and you would answer just look for objects you own in this folder.
In reality, my sharedwithme view has hundred of folders each which can have deep hierarchy.

I would like to find a simple query that would return all of them.
Is it possible without having to recursively lookup everything?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: this query returns in a flat list all the files and folders I have access to:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files

Comment: I get a 403 when trying to access that link.